# Different StoryBoard for each screen size swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uikit

How do I set Different Storyboards for each possible screen size in Swift?

I already have the Objective-C code.

Please, no Auto Layout, I don't need it.

But how do I convert it to Swift? I am new to Swift.

Here is code for Objective-C:

**AppDelgate.m** file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    // NSLog(@"Screen Height is %i", screenHeight);

    // grab correct storyboard depending on screen height
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self grabStoryboard];

    // display storyboard
    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {
    // determine screen size
    int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    switch (screenHeight) {
            // iPhone 4s
        case 480:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-4s" bundle:nil];
            break;

            // iPhone 5s
        case 568:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-5s" bundle:nil];
            break;

            // iPhone 6
        case 667:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6" bundle:nil];
            break;

            // iPhone 6 Plus
        case 736:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6-Plus" bundle:nil];
            break;

        default:
            // it's an iPad
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            break;
    }
    return storyboard;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using different storyboards for different screen sizes? universal xcode app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048543/using-different-storyboards-for-different-screen-sizes-universal-xcode-app)

Comment: its not duplicate i dont want to use auto layout

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to convert the code to the Swift you could reference the swift tutorial from Apple. You can check the book in the iBook Store or on the web. For your reference I converted the code into the Swift.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true


    // int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    // NSLog(@"Screen Height is %i", screenHeight);

    // grab correct storyboard depending on screen height

    let storyboard = grabStoryboard()

    // display storyboard
    self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}

func grabStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard
{
    // determine screen size
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard! = nil

    switch (screenHeight)
    {
    // iPhone 4s
    case 480:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main-4s", bundle: nil)
    // iPhone 5s
    case 568:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main-5s", bundle: nil)
    // iPhone 6
    case 667:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main-6", bundle: nil)
    // iPhone 6 Plus
    case 736:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main-6-Plus", bundle: nil)
    default:
    // it's an iPad
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    return storyboard
}
```

Comment: my aim to to use Different StoryBoard's for each diffrent screen size instead of autolayout and i already do this is objective c but dont know how to do this is swift. So can you pls assist me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Load different storyboard as per screen size:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    // NSLog(@"Screen Height is %i", screenHeight);
    // grab correct storyboard depending on screen height
   var storyboard: UIStoryboard = self.grabStoryboard()
    // display storyboard
    self.window.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}


func grabStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
    // determine screen size
    var screenHeight: Int = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard
    switch screenHeight {
    // iPhone 4s
    case 480:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard.storyboardWithName("Main-4s", bundle: nil)
    // iPhone 5s
    case 568:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard.storyboardWithName("Main-5s", bundle: nil)
    // iPhone 6
    case 667:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard.storyboardWithName("Main-6", bundle: nil)
    // iPhone 6 Plus
    case 736:
        storyboard = UIStoryboard.storyboardWithName("Main-6-Plus", bundle: nil)
    default:
    // it's an iPad
        storyboard = UIStoryboard.storyboardWithName("Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    return storyboard
}
```